# Analog joystick control, MCU or other option?

Tags: switches

I need to add some navigation control to a project I'm working on.  I'm looking at the [CTS 254](http://www.ctscorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Series-254-Ultra-Miniature-Joystick.pdf) which is just a two pot analog joystick.  I assume I can just get it's Xy coordinates by using a micro-controller with two adc inputs but I was wondering if there was an easier, perhaps code free way.  I really just want to get the xy coordinates up to my main processor over I2C.  Just wondering if there was another option here I might not have considered.

Comment: Buy a joystick with I2C interface. Still, you will need to implement the receiver side.

Comment: I'm sure there is some joystick driver. I have no part as exemple..

Comment: why don't you google for "spi/i2c adc" first?

Comment: If all you want is a joystick (and not "buttons" you might find on a Nintendo controller), then you probably face adding a separate microcontroller or else code. As far as finding one that already includes the micro and digitization and I2C communication, this is a shopping question and probably not a trivial one.

Comment: two DMMs with pc-link can be used to report a voltage to a PC